::error::Unable to get the ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN env variable
I am trying to upload my frontend to be hosted and served on github with github actions. I am using the following workflow:
name: Deploy Frontend

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, staging, frontend]
    paths:
      - 'frontend/**'
      - '.github/workflows/deploy_frontend.yml'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
      pages: write       # Added for GitHub Pages deployment
      id-token: write    # Necessary for actions/deploy-pages
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Debug REACT_APP_API_URL
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo -e "\e[32m@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\e[0m"
        echo -e "\e[32mREACT_APP_API_URL=${REACT_APP_API_URL}\e[0m"
        env
        echo $(env | grep ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN)
        # exit 1  # Commented out to allow the workflow to continue

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: '20'

    - name: Print Environment Variables and Secrets
      shell: bash
      env:
        REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT: ${{ env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT }}
      run: |
        echo -e "\e[32mREACT_APP_API_URL=${REACT_APP_API_URL}\e[0m"
        echo -e "\e[32mREACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=${REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT}\e[0m"
        env
        echo ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN=$(env | grep ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN)

    - name: Install dependencies
      shell: bash
      run: |
        cd frontend
        npm ci 2>&1 || (echo -e "\e[31mInstall dependencies step failed.\e[0m" && exit 1)

    - name: Build
      shell: bash
      run: |
        cd frontend
        mkdir -p build_logs
        TIMESTAMP=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        export REACT_APP_BUILD_TIME=$(TZ=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        echo -e "\e[32mBuilding with environment variables:\e[0m"
        env
        echo -e "\e[32m$(pwd)\e[0m"
        npm run build || (echo -e "\e[31mBuild step failed.\e[0m" && exit 1)

    - name: Setup Pages
      uses: actions/configure-pages@v4

    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
      with:
        path: './frontend/build'

    - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
      id: deployment
      uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4

    - name: Build Succeeded
      if: success()
      run: echo -e "\e[32mBuild succeeded.\e[0m"

    - name: Build Failed
      if: failure()
      shell: bash
      run: |
        echo -e "\e[31mBuild failed.\e[0m"
        exit 1


Locally, with npm start or npm run build; npx serve -s build, this serves fine, so I am not showing the code itself.
I want to test locally and then use github actions. Running the workflow like so:
~/src/personal_website$ act -j build-and-deploy -W .github/workflows/deploy_frontend.yml --secret-file /home/noams/src/personal_website/frontend/.secrets_frontend --env-file /home/noams/src/personal_website/frontend/.env

The secrets are
REACT_APP_API_URL=ZZZ
#REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:8080
GITHUB_TOKEN=YYY
#ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN=YYY
ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN=dummy [but also fails with the same token as GITHUB]
GITHUB_REPOSITORY=XXX

the .env file is as follows:
# frontend
# leave this here for the npm start to work
REACT_APP_API_URL=XXX
ENVIRONMENT="local"
REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT="local"
# some backend variables below

Notice a duplicate REACT_APP_API_URL exists in .secrets, because npm start only knows how to read an .env and not .secrets and i figured it won't matter much. (Can be nice to clean it up too).
Github configuration is irrelevant AFAIK, because this is running locally with act.
The error:
The step
    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v3
      with:
        path: './frontend/build'

fails with
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]     ::debug::File:/tmp/artifact.tar was found using the provided searchPath
| With the provided path, there will be 1 file uploaded
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]     ::debug::Root artifact directory is /tmp
| Artifact name is valid!
| Root directory input is valid!
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ❗  ::error::Unable to get the ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN env variable
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ❌  Failure - Main Upload artifact
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy] exitcode '1': failure
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ⚙  ::set-output:: artifact_id=
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ❌  Failure - Main Upload artifact
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy] exitcode '1': failure
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy] ⭐ Run Post Upload artifact
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]     docker cp src=/home/noams/.cache/act/actions-upload-pages-artifact@v3/ dst=/var/run/act/actions/actions-upload-pages-artifact@v3/
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   ✅  Success - Post Upload artifact
[Deploy Frontend/build-and-deploy]   Job failed
Error: Job 'build-and-deploy' failed

So there are two errors here I can't pinpoint:

::error::Unable to get the ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN env variable, even though I tried feeding it in and not feeding it in
::debug::Root artifact directory is /tmp | Artifact name is valid! | Root directory input is valid!, I have no idea what they are talking about

Any direction as to solving them would help.

Needless to say, GPT and Claude fail to help.

Will provide any additional details upon request, I hope I wrote everything relevant.

See https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/1929 and https://github.com/nektos/act/issues/329#issuecomment-1187246629.

Az per the threads @Azeem linked:
I have to run with the extra --artifact-server-path /tmp/artifacts and it solves it. Why? who knows. Maybe the github thread.
Complete run command:
act -j build-and-deploy \
-W .github/workflows/deploy_frontend.yml \
--secret-file /home/noams/src/personal_website/frontend/.secrets_frontend \
--env-file /home/noams/src/personal_website/frontend/.env \
--artifact-server-path /tmp/artifacts

